# Sorting UTC dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, date-sorting

EDIT 4/16/2012: I solved the issue of getting the timezone abbreviated into a letter format, had to download a third party sorting method and add a few things to get the desired results.  The only problem now is Daylight Savings Time handlers, but there are a bunch of subjects on that.  However if anyone knows how to handle UTC Daylight Savings hanlers, please feel free to help.

Thank you everyone.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
I've made an html table that I've binded with a javscript viewmodel using knockoutjs that pulls the info from a private server usin JSON function.  I'm trying to make each column sortable (click on the column header once to get everything in descending order according to that column's info; click header again to get everything in ascending, and a third time to get everything in it's original order).

PLEASE NOTE: I have searched for my problem and have seen other solutions, but nothing so far has worked for me.  I'm hoping to find a solution specific towards my code.

The Javascript ViewModel.js file is basically like this:

```
Event(column1, column2, ...., columnN){
    var self = this;
    self.column1 = column1;
    self.column2 = column2;
    .
    .
}

//Sort column2 that has the Dates (dd (day) HHMM (hours/minutes) mmm (month) yy (year) format)

self.sortColumn = "Column2"
self.sortAscending = true;

self.SortByDates = function(){
    if(self.sortColumn == "Column2")
        self.sortAscending = !self.sortAscending;
    else{
        self.sortColumn = "Column2"
        self.sortAscending = true;
    }
    self.rows.sort(function(a,b){
        if(self.sortAscending == true)
            for(self.Column2 in self.rows)
                return a.Column2 > b.Column2 ? 1 : a.Column2 < b.Column2 ? -1 : 0;
            else
                return a.Column2 < b.Column2 ? 1 : a.Column2 > b.Column2 ? -1 : 0;
    });
}

//specify location of server and info and get them
function getEvents(){
    $.getJSON("http://.........",
        function (data){
            $.each(data.d, function(i, item){
                handleEvent(item)
            })
        }
    );
}
//pushes (AKA populates) info from server into the table
function handleEvent(item){
    var newEvent = new Event(item.Column1InfoFromServer,
                                formatJSONDate(item.Column2DateInfoFromServer), .....)
    this.Model.rows.push(newEvent);
}
//Formats the date info from server into dd (day) HHMM (hours/minutes) mmm (month) yy (year)
formatJSONDate(jsonDate){
    var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
    return date.format("dd HHMM mmm yy");
}

this.Model = new ViewModel();
this.getEvents();
ko.applyBindings(this.Model);
```

I'm having one hell of a hard time getting the Date in its converted form (yes it HAS to be in that form --> actually, I still need to figure out how to include the time-zone abbreviation right after the 'HHMM' part based off of UTC).  So lets say I have "11 1136 Apr 12" and "22 1624 Jan 12" among other dates in the table.  Right now when I try sorting the table according to the dates, they don't sort appropriately.  Any help is appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: To be clear, I'm trying to display the timezones in military timezone codes (timezones 'A'-'Z').  Also, the dates being taken from the server are already in UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

I was looking at another question, and someone created a knockout grid addon:
https://github.com/ericmbarnard/KoGrid

I bet this might help you out :-)

*---OLD ANSWER for nostalgia----*

There are some great helper functions in the Underscore library, one of them being sort:

http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#sortBy

> sortBy_.sortBy(list, iterator, [context])  Returns a sorted copy of
>   list, ranked in ascending order by the results of running each value
>   through iterator. Iterator may also be the string name of the property
>   to sort by (eg. length).

```
_.sortBy([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function(num){ return Math.sin(num); });
=> [5, 4, 6, 3, 1, 2]
```

I'd give this a shot, along with creating a better model for your dates. It sounds like you need to store a property which is a unique point in time, along with a text value for the user.

Comment: Thanks, but I have looked at this in the past and while it made me think a little on how to handle the sorting, I overall didn't see it helping directly towards my situation.  I have gotten the sorting worked out by all that remains is converting the timezone into the military UTC abbreviations which is simply one letter abbreviations (A-Z).  I'm trying to get the date to display 'dd' (day) 'HH''MM''TZ'(hour/minutes/Timezone Abbreviation) mmm(month) yy(year).  Right now I'm getting back something like:

Comment: Sorry, looks like my last comment got cut off.  What I'm currently getting is something like "22 1626 (Wed Feb 22 2012 20:26:43 GMT(Eastern Standard Time)) Feb 12".  The question is how to get all that in the parenthesis translated into a single letter abbreviation for UTC timezones (A-Z).

Answer (score 0):

Well, to get numeric values for your date objects, sort by pDate.valueOf().  This will give you the # of millisecond since epoch.

However, there is an issue inside of your sort function, but I'm not sure what it is supposed to do.  You can't walk an object inside of a sort function and return values like that.

Comment: Thanks, I did a little re-working and got the sorting date to ascend and descend properly by not converting the date info strait out of the server.  Instead I kept it in the milliseconds from 1970 format and created a dummy variable equal to that in my Events() section.  I then run my sorting method based of that and show the converted format in the table.  However, I'm still not sure how to display the appropriate timezone and I still have not been able to figure out how to get the table to return to its default state.